# Fixing Input UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, authentication, input

In my code I'm trying to code a password login loop that will keep requiring a password input until a correct password (defined in an .env file) is given. However, when I run the code below I get an "UnboundLocalError cannot access local variable 'input' where it is not associated with a value."
Any ideas?

Here is my code that gives the error:
`from decouple import config

from speech_rec import speak, take_user_input

LOGIN=config("SHA-512")

def login():
while True:
input=input("PASSWORD: ")
if input==LOGIN:
break
else:
speak("Try Again")
continue
login()
#rest of code
for i in range(10):
print(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because you used one of python's [*built-in*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) (`input`) as a variable name.

```
import builtins

print("input" in dir(builtins))
#True
```

Try to give your variable a different name :

```
from speech_rec import speak, take_user_input

LOGIN=config("SHA-512")

def login():
    while True:
        input_val = input("PASSWORD: ")
        if input_val == LOGIN:
            break
        else:
            speak("Try Again")
        continue
```